# When does getInputStream() return null?

Tags: java, sockets

When we call `Socket.getInputStream()` the second time after creating client it returns null. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

It will *feel* like a returned null value if you've used this pattern by accident:

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
   is = socket.getInputStream();
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO will be logged once logging is implemented...
  // e.printStackTrace();
}
is.read(); //  <-- NPE in case IOException...
```

Double check your code, this could be the reason for your NPE.

Answer (score 1):

According to [its documentation `Socket.getInputStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream%28%29) can never return `null`. It either returns an `InputStream` *or* it throws an `IOException`.

If it throws an `IOException` then you either closed the socket, the other side closed the socket or some other problem occurred during communication.